# Thumbnails Bootstrap 3.X de distinta height

Tags: bootstrap-3

Estoy trabajando con el componente thumbnail de bootstrap. el html sería.

```
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <div class="img1"><img src="./images/img3.jpg" alt="" /></div>
      <div class="img2"><img src="./images/icono.jpg" alt="" /></div>
      <div class="main-text">
        <h3>Título</h3>
        <p>texto</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Mi problema es que si tengo varios thumnails con `<p>texto</p>` de distinto tamaño, éstos tienen distinta altura. He probado algunas opciones propuestas por otras personas pero no consigo que me funcione.
Gracias.